# What is a "wreckless careerism"?

Tags: meaning, errors

I have come across the following sentence:

> The quickness of her ascent, and the fact that she revamped each orchestra’s administration before suddenly moving on, has led some in music business circles to charge her with *wreckless careerism*.
>   <sub>*[Source](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/02/15/arts/the-feisty-pathfinder-of-the-philharmonic.html?pagewanted=3)*</sub>

After having considered that *The New York Times*, as far as I know, does not use slang words in its written texts, I wonder what *wreckless careerism* means. My problem is that *wreckless* gets no support from any dictionary I have consulted, but this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=wreckless&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1920&year_end=2000) shows that this word exists, so it seems difficult to rule out the case as a mere typo.

[image]

Comment: Wreckless is just a typo, albeit common, for reckless.

Comment: *OneLook* is a good resource for checking many dictionaries and other references: http://onelook.com/?w=wreckless&ls=a

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, but those numbers on the y axis are sooo small...

I, like you I'm guessing, believe they are using "wreckless" to mean the same as "reckless". So let's assume that is the case, and compare their use.

[image]

If you compare the y axis numbers here, you'll see the significance is roughly 1,000 times greater here than in your graph.

The NYT is rather famous (notorious) for having [linguistic dicta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_York_Times_Manual_of_Style_and_Usage) mandating their staff hang onto obsolete words, usages, and rules long past the time that the rest of the continent has left them by. If I had to take a guess, I'd say "wreckless" is one of those.

Or it could just be a spellcheck/typo that got left in because technically that is an alternate spelling for "reckless".

If you write them, you may get an answer as to which it is.

Comment: +1 for *Or it could just be a spellcheck/typo that got left in because technically that is an alternate spelling for "reckless".* A very few English words may be spelled with either *r* or *wr*.

Comment: *Wreckless* is not “old-style” for *reckless*.  It is ***erroneous*** for the same.

Comment: @tchrist - Not an expert on this particular word, but the entry in your answer has both "erron." (erroneous) and "obs." (obsolete) in it. My interpretation of that would be that they are saying it used to be considered correct, but no longer.

Comment: @tchrist: it -could- mean there have been no wrecks so far.

Comment: @Mitch - The more I think on this, the more I'm with tchrist on it. It could indeed mean that, but giving it a slightly different meaning IMHO makes the situation even worse. It is used so rarely, and is such a likely misspelling of "reckless", that now you don't know which meaning was intended.

Comment: @T.E.D. It -could- mean 'without wrecks' but it doesn't. Its a plane outwrite mispelling.

Comment: @Mitch. Great turn of the sentence, choosing those misspelt terms...

Comment: Please include a link for the ngram

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a better dictionary, as the OED entry for ***wreckless*** plainly reads:

> **wreckless**, obs. erron. f. **reckless** *a.*

Comment: ... or even [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wreckless#Adjective_2).